# WooCommerce order is incorrect discount price when updated quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Regarding I would like to create an order and apply a coupon code at the admin screen with detail below

Coupon code setting:

[image]

Order Detail:

[image]

When I changed a product “Minced Pork with Wolffia” quantity from 10 to be 5, a discount price show incorrect amount is 75.00 THB which it actually should be show 100.00 THB discount

[image]

But if I try to remove the coupon code and apply it again, It is correctly discount price.

[image]

Is it properly logic to re-apply coupon code when I have update the product quantity? Could you please advise.

PS. I have tested it with a new store that doesn't install any plugins.